# Hodge--Tate weights of an abelian surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $X$ be an abelian surface over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. When does $X$ have distinct Hodge--Tate weights (in étale cohomology)?

Comment: By Hodge-Tate comparison for abelian varieties (proved by Tate), Hodge-Tate weights are the same as Hodge numbers, so for $X$ an abelian variety of dim $g$ they are $\binom{g}{i} \binom{g}{n-i}$ in degree $n$. These are never all $\leq 1$ (I guess this is what you mean by distinct Hodge-Tate weights) unless $g=1$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger do you mean that *the multiplicity* of the Hodge--Tate weight $i$ is the product of binomial coefficients? or am I misunderstanding the terminology?

Comment: I'm claiming that $\binom{g}{i} \binom{g}{n-i}$ is the multiplicity of $\mathbf{C}_p(-i)$ in the Hodge-Tate decomposition of $H^n(X_{\bar K}, \mathbf{Q}_p)$. This follows from the fact that $H^n = \bigwedge^n H^1$ as Galois representations, and that $H^1$ has Hodge-Tate weights $0$ and $1$, both with multiplicity $g$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger but then the original comment was slightly sloppily worded: "Hodge-Tate weights...they are...". Do you agree?